# how to calculate the x and y co-ordinates in a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to determine the x and y co-ordinates by the data obtained from getImageData.  Here is a sample of my code:

```
var img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
var pix = [],
    coords = [];
for (var i = 0; i < img.data.length; i+=4) {
  if (img.data[i]!== 0){
    pix.push(i);
  }
}

for (var j in pix) {
  //wrong co-ordinate
  var y = Math.floor(pix[j]/c.width); 
  //don't know how to determine x position
  var x = 0;
  coords.push({
    x:x,
    y:y
  });
}
```

Comment: Co-ordinates of what ?

Comment: Suppose if the array pix contains a value 16500 I want to know where is that pixel in the canvas in terms of x and y co-ordinates

Comment: Which pixel ? All the pixels ? Are you trying to create matrix of each pixel ? How about `i ... j` loop then ?

Comment: Hey @decatron if I give a array containing [{x: , y: , R: , G: , B: ,A: }] for valid pixel will that work? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Not all the pixel. The only pixels in which there is some content i.e if(img.data[i]!=0)

Comment: Could you please help us help you by making this question [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
What is ctx? How can we test this ourselves to make sure it's working or not?

Comment: @ayan no I don't need the data for every pixel as I want the ones which has some content in it.

Comment: @seedart here ctx is the canvas context and c is the canvas object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main block of calculation is:

```
if (img.data[i] !== 0) {
    // Please look up in the explaination part for this.
    j = i / 4;
    quo = Math.floor(j / cols);
    pix.push({
      x: quo,
      y: j - (quo * cols)
    });
  }
```

If this is the pixel array we are assuming:

```
0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7
```

Then corresponding imageData would be:

```
0,1,2,3     4,5,6,7     8,9,10,11   12,13,14,15 
16,17,18,19 20,21,22,23 24,25,26,27 28,29,30,31
```

Firstly we iterate `i += 4`, jumping block to block getting 0,4,8,...
When we do `j = i / 4;` we convert this image data to our original pixel array, eg. if i = 20, in pixel array its representing 5.

Now once we get the pixel array, for x-coordinate:

```
quo = Math.floor(j / cols);
```

Divide it by the columns, and it gives the row it belongs.

While finding the column index: we do:

```
j - (quo * cols);
```

This means, (quo * cols) gives the first element on that row. Subtracting it gives me, after how many elements from the first element in that row, I will get it. This is nothing but the column index. and our x-coordinate in this case.

Please check the following code:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
  context = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  rows = 512,
  cols = 512,
  img,
  pix = [],
  co_ords = [],
  quo;
// sets the height and width for the canvas.
canvas.width = cols;
canvas.height = rows;
// append the canvas to the document.
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
// draw a simple rectangle at (10,10)
context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
// extract the imageData for the canvas.
img = context.getImageData(0, 0, rows, cols);
// iterate for every 4th data, as there is a (R,G,B,A) set mapped for every pixel.
for (i = 0; i < img.data.length; i += 4) {
  // check if its a valid pixel(non-empty)
  if (img.data[i] !== 0) {
    // Please look up in the explaination part for this.
    j = i / 4;
    quo = Math.floor(j / cols);
    pix.push({
      x: quo,
      y: j - (quo * cols)
    });
    
  }
}

console.log(pix);
```

Comment: Hey @decatron, let me know if this was it what you were looking for. I will document and update the explanations.

Comment: Will you please post the explanation for the calculation?

Comment: @decatron Cool, updated some explanation. Please validate.

Answer (score 1):

Given the pixel address as index and knowing the image width.

```
x = (Math.floor(index/4)) % width;
y = Math.floor(index/(4 * width));
```